# sync folder between server and desktop objective c mac os

Tags: objective-c, amazon-s3, synchronization

I have project where i want to sync the folders continuously:

- `Folder_server` is on server
- `Folder_desktop` is on my mac system.

I want to sync both of the folders at run time.

Below are the steps I am doing:

1. Data from server: Array of dictionary containing: Name of file, Modification date, Size of file
2. Data from Local: Array of dictionary containing: Name of file, Modification date, Size of file
3. Compare the file name

If file is absent it gets copied in respective folder.

If the file is present in both of the folders it checks for the modification date-time and modified the file which have previous date (lower date).

Below is the logic:

```
-(void)get_localfile{
}

-(void)get_serverfile{
}
-(void)Compare_Files{
    //Upload FILES
    for(int i=0;i<[Array_LocalFiles count];i++){
        if(![Array_serverobjects containsObject:[Array_LocalFiles objectAtIndex:i]]){
            //Upload to server
        }else{

            NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            for(int j=0;j<[arr_Dict_server count];j++){
                if([[[arr_Dict_server objectAtIndex:j]valueForKey:@"file"] isEqualToString:[Array_LocalFiles objectAtIndex:i]]){
                    NSLog(@"file==server file=>%@",[[arr_Dict_server objectAtIndex:j]valueForKey:@"file"]);
                    NSLog(@"file==local file=>%@",[[arr_Dict_Localfile objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"file"]);
                     dic=[arr_Dict_server objectAtIndex:j];

                    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];

                    NSDate *date_server = [dateFormat dateFromString:[dic valueForKey:@"timestamp"]];
                    NSDate *date_local = [dateFormat dateFromString:[[arr_Dict_Localfile objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"timestamp"]];

                    if ( [date_server timeIntervalSinceDate:date_local] == 0) {
                        // //NSLog(@"Dates are equal.no action perform");


                    }
                    if ( [date_server laterDate:date_local] == date_local ) {
                        //NSLog(@"%@ file upload to server",[Array_LocalFiles objectAtIndex:i]);

                    }
                    if ( [date_server laterDate:date_local] == date_server) {
                        //NSLog(@"%@ file dowloaded from server",[dic valueForKey:@"file"]);

                    }


                    break;
                }
            }
        }


    }
    //download FILES
    for(int i=0;i<[Array_serverobjects count];i++){
        if(![Array_LocalFiles containsObject:[Array_serverobjects objectAtIndex:i]]){
            //NSLog(@"%@ file dowloaded from server",[Array_serverobjects objectAtIndex:i]);                
        }
    }
}
```

Now the Scenario is:

1. `desktopfolder` is blank and folder in desktop contains file name `Apple.doc`
2. I start my logic. So it will check whether `apple.doc` is present in desktopfolder. If not, it copies the file in `desktopfolder`.
3. Now after copying the file in `desktopfolder`, both the folders contain the file named `apple.doc`. So it will check for modification date now. So everytime the modification date of `desktopfolder` is latest (as `desktopfolder` had copied the file later).
4. Now as per the logic the file which have last modified date is latest file and that file get copy in the respective folder (whether on server or on desktop).

Now the problem is when I try to edit the file from desktop or replace it from the server it is not allowing me to edit it.

If I try to edit the file it always modify the file contain with the existing one.

Comment: As an alternative, you could use the `aws s3 sync` command from the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I want to perform this by coding.